# Set custom header in Dart's HttpRequest

Tags: dart, httprequest

I need to set a custom header in my HttpRequest in order to use encryption in an S3 bucket. The header which I want to set the header `x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm` but I always get an

> SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified. 'x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm' is not a valid HTTP header field name.

Sure, its not a valid HTTP header field name, but why cannot I add any header I want?

My code

```
  HttpRequest.request(url, method: 'PUT',
      requestHeaders: {
        'x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm': 'AES256',
        'x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key': base64Key,
        'x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5': md5Key
      }, sendData: _uploadingJob.file)
  .then((req) => req.onReadyStateChange.where(
      (e) => req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE)
      .first.then((e) {
       print('Request sent.');
      }));
```

Comment: Seems to work here https://dartpad.dartlang.org/aeb871cd92d96595e94c

Comment: It's just not my day :'(

Comment: The weird thing is when I copy the source from your question dartpad and WebStorm add a lot of spaces before the `-`. Are these some weird dashes?

Comment: Nop, no weird dashes in DartEditor...

Comment: With spaces in the names I get the same error, when I remove them (keep the dashes) it works.

Comment: Woooooot? I just copied the code from dartpad and it works. What's going on here? Probably some sneaky ninja spaces or w/e. Feel free to post an answer that there is an issue with the spaces and I will accept it right away.

Comment: Very weird. Could this be a similar cause with your other problem? You could try to copy the working code from `main` back to where it should be.

Comment: I think I already tried this a couple of times, but I'll give it another shot. Thanks, you've been so many times my hero ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something weird with your dashes.
When I copy the source from your question dartpad and WebStorm add a lot of spaces before the `-`.
Try to remove and re-add them.